# Add ISO inside Datastore of VMware VSphere Client

Tags: iso-image, esxi

I rent a physical server inside OVH datacenter, I installed VMware ESXi 5.5 on it.

I did not find where to add an ISO within the datastore. Should I install a plugin ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After half-hour looking :

- Clic on `Inventory`
- Left Panel > Clic on your VMWare ESXi server IP (or domain), root of the tree
- Right panel> Storage > Clic right on your datastore name, `datastore1` by default
- Choose `Browse Datastore`

I was confused by VMware's user experience design, `datastore1` is not presented as a button.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use command line :
for first volume
      cd /vmfs/volumes/datastore1
or for another volume
      cd /vmfs/volumes/datastore2

and then use wget command to download the iso file from external sources
for example iso image of windows 2008 from microsoft serve :

wget http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/5/E/75EC4E54-5B02-42D6-8879-D8D3A25FBEF7/7601.17514.101119-1850_x64fre_server_eval_en-us-GRMSXEVAL_EN_DVD.iso

Comment: Note the http in the download URL.  This may actually be necessary.  See [this forum](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/ESXi-Discussions/6-7-0-httpClient-true-but-wget-error-getting-response-Cannot/td-p/2863980) for people having a problem with https when trying to download iso files onto esxi datastore.